# An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the ImportImage operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am getting following error when I am trying to import vhd file from s3 into EC2

I have following Policy attached to my profile:

```
IAMFullAccess
VMImportExportRoleForAWSConnector
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AmazonVPCFullAccess
IAMReadOnlyAccess
AmazonRoute53FullAccess
RegionRestrictions
```

And I have created trusted role as below:

```
{ 
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": { "Service": "vmie.amazonaws.com" },
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Condition": {
        "StringEquals":{
           "sts:Externalid": "amosvmimport"
        }
     }
  }
```

]
}

And I have created trusted policy as below:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:FullAccess"
     ],
     "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cloudforms.vhd"
     ]
  },
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
     ],
     "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cloudforms.vhd/*"
     ]
  },
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action":[
        "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
        "ec2:CopySnapshot",
        "ec2:RegisterImage",
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:FullAccess"
     ],
     "Resource": "*"
  }
 ]
}
```

Following command run successfully:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name amosvmimport --assume-role-policy-document file://trust-policy.json

aws iam put-role-policy --role-name amosvmimport --policy-name amosvmimport --policy-document file://role-policy.json
```

But when I an trying to run:

```
aws ec2 import-image --disk-containers file://containers.json --region ap-south-1
```

it is giving me error as below:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the ImportImage operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Could you please let me know if I am missing any policy for this operation?

Comment: what are your permissions in the whole aws account? it seems that the use who are trying to run this command doesn't have permission to doit.doesn't have anything to do with your file. can you verify your permissions?

Comment: You have created a role, but you do not appear to be using the role in your `aws ec2 import-image` command. Why did you create the role?